# 'Customer' does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, constructor

I can not figure out why I get this error. 
As the code is quite a lot and I don't get what might be wrong I post a link to all the files.
If someone might figure out why I get this error " 'Customer' does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments " ... an hour I am stuck on this... [this are the files](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/92037912/Pets%20Hotel%202.zip)
The error is in page book.aspx

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) 
{ 
   Customer c1 = new Customer(txtFirstname.Text, txtLastname.Text, txtAddress.Text, txtZip.Text, txtCity.Text); 
   Pet p1 = new Pet(txtSpecies.Text, txtName.Text,c1); 
   service.pets.Add(p1); 
}
```

Customer->

```
public Customer(int customerId, string firstname, string lastname, string address, string zipcode, string city, string email, string phone) 
     : base(firstname, lastname) 
{ 
    this.firstname = firstname; 
    this.lastname = lastname; 
}
```

Comment: post the code here :D don't let the users download the file.

Comment: If you can't take the time to isolate your code to where the problem is (for example, by posting that very constructor) -- why should we take the time to help?

Comment: the constructor accepts (`int customerId, string firstname, string lastname, string address, string zipcode, string city, string email, string phone`) 8 parameters, not 5.

Comment: if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack) {
            Customer c1 = new Customer(txtFirstname.Text, txtLastname.Text,
            txtAddress.Text, txtZip.Text, txtCity.Text);
            Pet p1 = new Pet(txtSpecies.Text, txtName.Text,c1);
            service.pets.Add(p1);
}
Customer->

public Customer(int customerId, string firstname, string lastname, string address, string zipcode, string city, string email, string phone) : base(firstname, lastname) 
    {
        
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor for Customer class is -

```
public Customer(int customerId, string firstname, string lastname,
                string address, string zipcode, string city, string email,
                string phone)
```

And from Book.aspx.cs you are creating instance like -

```
Customer c1 = new Customer(txtFirstname.Text, txtLastname.Text,
            txtAddress.Text, txtZip.Text, txtCity.Text);
```

Replace it with -

```
Customer c1 = new Customer(txtFirstname.Text, txtLastname.Text,
            txtAddress.Text, txtZip.Text, txtCity.Text, string.Empty,
              string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

Comment: This is just a workaround, you should really conisder of modifying the design/approach of your code.